# How to make GraphFrame from Edge DataFrame only

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, graphframes

From [this](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/user-guide.html), "A GraphFrame can also be constructed from a single DataFrame containing edge information. The vertices will be inferred from the sources and destinations of the edges."

However when I look into its [API doc](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/api/python/graphframes.html#graphframes.GraphFrame), it seems there is no way to create one.

Has someone tried to create a GraphFrame using edge DataFrame only? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The graphframes scala API has a function called [fromEdges](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/graphframes/GraphFrame.scala#L701) which generates a graphframe from a edge dataframe. As far as I can overlook it this function isn't avaiable in pyspark, but you can do something like:

```py
##something

verticesDf = edgesDF.select('src').union(edgesDF.select('dst'))
verticesDf = verticesDf.withColumnRenamed('src', 'id')

##more something
```

to achieve the same.

Answer (score 6):

In order to avoid duplicates in the vertices list I would add a distinct

```
verticesDf=edgesDf \
     .select("src") \ 
     .union(edgesDf.select("dst")) \
     .distinct() \
     .withColumnRenamed('src', 'id')

verticesDf.show()

graph=GraphFrame(verticesDf,edgesDf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative that doesn't read the whole data twice:

```
nodes = (
    edges
    .withColumn("id", F.explode(F.array(F.col("src"), F.col("dst"))))
    .select("id")
    .distinct()
)
```